Does $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{2k-1}}$ converge or diverge?
The question concerns the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{2k-1}}.$$
I am wondering how to show if it is convergent or divergent. I did it with a calculator and I think it converges to -0.67, but from both sides I think. I am not sure how to write it down or show it without a calculator. Can someone explain it to me? Could that someone explain it in simple, that would be really nice.   Thank you.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

This question is similar to: Showing that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{i^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ is convergent. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

For $k\geq 1$, consider the sequence defined as $$a_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k-1}}$$
So, $(a_k)_k$ is a positive decreasing sequence:
$$a_k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k-1}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(k+1)-1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+1}}=a_{k+1}, \space \forall k\geq 1$$
Then, we can write the given series as follows:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{2k-1}}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^ka_k$$
The series is convergent for Leibniz criterion.
